# Is there support for git rebasing in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode4

Can one **rebase** to integrate changes from one branch to another from within Xcode? I know Xcode supports merge but I couldn't find anything for rebasing.

Answer (score 9):

It does not since it tries to provide an abstraction over the version control system in use. If want  a Mac GUI for git you could use gitx or sourcetree

Comment: Even if it's very much NOT the answer I want to hear, thank you for providing it.

Comment: Using Xcode no...only using terminal. This tutorial in Source Control using Xcode might be helpful since it refers to terminal git commands if the action is not available in menu http://iosdevblog.com/2016/01/23/source-control-in-xcode-and-terminal/

Answer (score 2):

While there isn't a git rebase function, you can still sort of rebase.

1. Checkout the branch you want to rebase
2. Click Source Control -> Pull
3. select the branch you want to rebase onto
4. check off "rebase local changes onto upstream changes"

This should rebase your current branch onto the target branch. Merge conflicts need to be handled manually (deleting the merge conflict annotations in the code).